# Producer, consumer, and handler with messaging queue

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, ibm-mq

I am involved in a project which consists of apps below:

- Producer application: receives messages from clients via ASP.NET web api, and enqueues messages into a message queue.
- Consumer application: dequeues messages from the message queue above, and sends messages to Handler application below.
- Handler application: receives messages from Consumer application, and sends the message to external application, if that failed, sends them to dead queue.

The problem is that:
Consumer dequeues messages off the queue, and send them to Handler. Then Consumer is **blocked** (via background threads using async) waiting for Handler's process. That is, Consumer performs RPC call to Handler app.

If Handler either successfully sends the messages to external app, or if that failed, successfully enqueues them to a dead queue, Consumer commits the dequeuing. (removes message off the queue)

If either of both (external app or dead queue) above failed, consumer rollbacks the dequeuing (puts message back to queue)

My question is that

- What is the pros and cons of using Handlers app, comparing Consumer performs Handler's logic in addition to Consumer's current logic?
- Is it better to remove Handler application, and integrates Handler's logic to Consumer application? So Consumer talks to external application directly, and handles dead queue. One fewer application to maintain.

Comment: I do not see any pros for keeping Handler and Consumer app separate. With a facts given, by building RPC call above MQ messaging the only thing you have is a messaging with additional RPC problems. Either use MQ or RPC.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be perfectly clear: in the abstract sense, you have two entities - a producer and a consumer. The producer sends the original message, and the consumer processes it.  There is no need to muddy the water by adding details about "handler" as it is a logical part of the consuming process.

It seems then that your real question (and also mine) is "what value does `consumer` (your definition) add?" Keep in mind that none are "talking" directly to one another - they are communicating via a message queue.  In that regard, if it is easier to have the ultimate processing piece dequeue the message directly, rather than having some intermediate pipe, then do that.

Comment: What do you mean by this sentence? " In that regard, if it is easier to have the ultimate processing piece dequeue the message directly, rather than having some intermediate pipe, then do that." We currently have producer, consumer, queue, and handler. Which parts do you suggest to remove?

Comment: What is "handler" doing? I'm referring to that as a pipe. It seems to be rather redundant.

Comment: Handler basically just passes messages from Consumer to external application.

Comment: Yes, which is redundant since that's ostensibly the message broker's job.